# Is foreign key serializable in Kdb+?

Tags: database, time-series, kdb

I saw doc said [foreign key cannot be splayed or partitioned](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb%2B/#1412-foreign-keys-and-link-columns), but DOES it mean that foreign key cannot be serialized/persisted ?

If so, why this mechanism cannot be persisted while linked column can ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A keyed table can be saved to disk using `set`

```
q)kt:([eid:1001 1002 1003;name:`Dent`Beeblebrox`Prefect] iq:98 42 126)
q)`:kt set kt
`:kt
q)get  `:kt
eid  name      | iq
---------------| ---
1001 Dent      | 98
1002 Beeblebrox| 42
1003 Prefect   | 126
```

When you run `get` the full table is read in to memory.

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/get/

This is okay when data is small but when it grows large splayed tables are used as they can be `mapped`, bringing in only the rows you need.

https://code.kx.com/q/database/

A table in kdb is a list of dictionaries

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/dictsandtables/#column-dictionaries

A keyed table is a dictionary

https://code.kx.com/q/kb/faq/#keyed-tables

kdb+ on disk operates using row based indexing. This is counter to how keyed tables work, as they are dictionaries they operate on key lookups not row indexes.

```
q)data:([] id:`a`b`c`d; v:1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4) // Sample table
q)data
id v
------
a  1.1
b  2.2
c  3.3
d  4.4
q)data[0 1] // Pull data using row indexes
id v
------
a  1.1
b  2.2
q)data:`id xkey data //Turn the table in to a keyed table
q)data
id| v
--| ---
a | 1.1
b | 2.2
c | 3.3
d | 4.4
q)data[0 1] // Cannot index on row
'type
  [0]  data[0]
       ^
q)data[`a] // Key value matching type of key columns needed
v| 1.1
```

A linked column simply points to indexes in the parent table meaning this translates well to the on disk format.